# How can I have a directional projectile coming out?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This problem is because when I want instantiating the projectile it doesnt come out the same way as the direction

Comment: Where exactly do you spawn the projectile?

Comment: @derHugo In a 2D game. From a player, there is a aim angle which is 360 degrees of aim, then the projectile comes out from this aim and instantiates the prefab. Problem is the prefab is facing right and if I were to aim left and shoot the projectile will shoot out but face to the right always.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Angle` is the same angle you want the projectile to have:

`transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Angle, Vector3.forward);`

If it's facing 90 degrees away from the correct direction, either rotate the sprite to face upwards, or try adding/substracting 90 to/form `Angle` like:
`transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Angle - 90, Vector3.forward);`

Comment: thank you for the answer. However, because in a 2D environment I am shooting in 360 degrees around me. My prefab is a directional projectile facing or pointing to the right. But if I were to shoot from my left, it will shoot out but the projectile faces right still.

Comment: Misunderstood your question at first, sorry. Edited my answer, try it now.

Comment: Yeah but its a live aiming angle, so depending on what my float aimAngle is the projectile will face in that direction

Comment: Just replace the Angle in my code with whatever you want the angle to be. I do not see a float aimAngle in your code so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that instantiates the projectile?

Comment: ok but you have to tell me first where you are instantiating from, or maybe show that code.

Comment: @SpicyCatGames I have included it inside

Comment: @SeanCarey I have included it inside as well, the instantiation

Comment: @SpicyCatGames sorry the aimAngle is actually Angle

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your CastSpell function to the following and tell me if it works:

```
  void CastSpell(int slot) {
      var spellObject = Instantiate(spellPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
      var mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
      var dir = mousePos - transform.position;
      var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + 90;
      spellObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle - 90, Vector3.forward);
      spellObject.GetComponent<SpellController>().srcPlayerID = playerID;
      StartCoroutine(SpellCooldown(slot, gameConstants.spellCooldown));
  }
```

Comment: Im using controllers(gamepad) and not mouse

Comment: In your ProjectileController script, you have a float variable named Angle. Where in the code do you set the value of Angle?

Comment: thank you i edited the code below to include where i set my float angle, its basically s=using the analog stick of the controller to set the aimAngle which is 360 degrees

Comment: Can you also show the code that calculates aim?

Comment: Oh wait it isn;t that section below my code?

Comment: You have a vector named 'aim'. Show me the code that sets the value of that vector.

Comment: Ok one moment sean